# How to modify a project Makefile to integrate boehm gc

Tags: c, linker, apache-phoenix, boehm-gc

Please, is someone familiar with Boehm GC?

I want to use it in the word-count app of Phoenix (https://github.com/kozyraki/phoenix), but I fail to modify the Makefile to include the GC library.

On the documentation page of Boehm, they only provide a simple c example and a command to compile it from the GC directory tree. I can't find any tutorial on how to link it with an existing project.

Thanks

Comment: Add the Boehm library in the dependency of the exe and in the linker line.

Answer (score 0):

The following steps should help you:

1. ensure libgc is installed on your host, e.g. on Ubuntu type like this: sudo apt install libgc-dev
2. your source files (which call GC_* functions) should include <gc.h>.
3. add -lgc to LIBS variable in the Makefile